# Google Sheets - How to concatenate a range based on a matching value in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that lists through filenames of an image gallery. Each row represents a new image; has a unique filename, but has an associated non-unique page title, as follows:

| title | filename |
| --- | --- |
| Page 1 | img1.jpg |
| Page 1 | img2.jpg |
| Page 1 | img3.jpg |
| Page 2 | img4.jpg |
| Page 2 | img5.jpg |
| Page 2 | img6.jpg |

What I need to do is concatenate each file name into a single cell, (formatted in a particular way), as follows:

| title | filename |
| --- | --- |
| Page 1 | img1.jpg///img2.jpg///img3.jpg/// |
| Page 2 | img4.jpg///img5.jpg///img6.jpg/// |

I have tried everything I can think of using COUNTIF, UNIQUE but I can't seem to get anywhere.

I would just write a basic formula for if A1 = "Page 1"... but I have thousands of rows to do so it would take me days and days to write them all out manually changing the formula.

Oh wise wizards of Stackoverflow, please work your wizened magic and help me out with a formula? I have no idea how to use VBA but am willing to poke around if necessary.

Many many thank-yous!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the datarange in A2:B, try

```
=arrayformula({unique(A2:A), trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(A2:A))=A2:A)*len(A2:A), B2:B&"///",),,50000)))})
```

Change range to suit and see if that works?

[image: Example]

If you don't want to have any spaces in the output, try

```
=arrayformula({unique(A2:A), substitute(trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(A2:A))=A2:A)*len(A2:A), B2:B&"///",),,50000)))," ",)})
```

Comment: You are an absolute hero! This is 99% perfect; I just need the output to not have trailing spaces between each value - that's what the /// is for. I can't quite find the part of the formula that is adding that space? Thank you so much! You've saved me HOURS!!!

Comment: You can add a substitute to the function. See my updated answer (second formula).